# Range of values for shades of orange

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, lab-color-space

I am new to MATLAB and am working on a program which requires me to analyse the shades of the color orange. I am working in the Lab color space and am stuck with what range of L, a and b values to take for the different orange shades. Had it been HSV, it would have been easier, I would then just give a range for Hue (like, from 18 to 30) , which would then include all orange shades. Please help me out with the range in Lab.

Comment: Could you convert Lab to RGB then to HSV? I don't know much about this, sorry, just an idea.

Comment: @David, yes I could do that. But working in the lab color space will keep me closer to actual human perception of colors, since the lab color space includes  all perceivable colors.

Comment: @CobraCobra can't you convert that hue range from HSV to Lab?

Answer (score 1):

If you are inexperienced in the Lab colour space, but do know your way around the RGB or HSV colour spaces, then I advise to convert you Lab colours to HSV and vice versa. This can be done with [`lab2rgb`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/lab2rgb.html), [`rgb2hsv`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) and the other way around with [`hsv2rgb`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hsv2rgb.html) and [`rgb2lab`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2lab.html).

Firstly, this has the benefit that you know what colours you are using in RGB or HSV colour space, while you do work in Lab.

Secondly, you won't learn to work in Lab colour space if you don't start somewhere you do know something about. Starting with HSV and converting what you know to Lab will give you some information on the Lab colour space and how it behaves.

Lastly, you could also ignore my second point and just accept your knowledge of HSV as enough to work with. Using MATLAB and the functions I mention enables you to use only HSV knowledge, but work in the Lab colour space without the need to fully understand it. This, of course, depends on your goals and questions.